# Count Category products with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to count products inside each category like I have a category A that have two childs B and C.

In B category have 10 products and C category have 5 Products.

I want to write a query that count product like `A = 15` `B = 10` `C = 5`.

I have wrote a query that count only for child categories.

My query is given below

```
SELECT 
    c.`id`,
    c.`parent_id`,
    c.`name`,
    c.`slug`,
    c.`route_id`,
    c.`description`,
    c.`excerpt`,
    c.`sequence`,
    c.`image`,
    c.`seo_title`,
    c.`meta`,
    c.`enabled`,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(`product_id`)
        FROM
            HM_category_products
        WHERE
            HM_category_products.category_id IN (SELECT 
                    HM_categories.`id`
                FROM
                    HM_categories
                WHERE
                    (id = c.`id` OR id = c.`parent_id`))) AS count
FROM
    `HM_categories` AS c
```

EDITED :- Below is my tables structure. This is just an example.

```
    Category Table

    id  parent_id   name                        slug                             enabled
    1   0           Mobiles & Tablets           mobiles-tablets                     1
    2   1           Mobile Phones               mobile-phones                       1
    3   1           Tablets                     tablets                             1
    4   1           Mobile Accessories          mobile-accessories                  1
    5   0           Electronics & Computers     electronics-computers               1   
    6   5           Cameras & Accessories       cameras-accessories                 1
    7   5           TV - Video - Audio          tv-video-audio                      1





    Category Product Table 

    product_id  category_id
    1               2 
    2               2 
    3               2 
    4               2 
    5               3 
    6               2 
    7               3 
    8               3 
    9               3 
    10              2 
    11              3 
    12              2 
    13              2 
    14              2 
    15              2
```

Comment: It would help if u post your data shema and some rows of example data.

Answer (score 1):

You hav to use the "Group by" with something like:

```
SELECT 
    category_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    HM_category_products
GROUP BY category_id
```

This would get your table *HM_category_products* Grouped by category_id so will know how mane rows of each category its in the table, whats mean you will know the number of product of each category. Then you can join this resulting table with category one to get the category info. (Sorry for my english)

> The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate
>   functions to group the result-set by one or more columns. [SQL GROUP BY Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

for more info abaut "Group by" read 
[12.16.2 GROUP BY Modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and
[12.16.1 GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

EDIT: I see now what you whant. I already give you the direction but here its a step furder: DISCLAIMER: THIS QUERY ITS JUST EXAMPLE, IT DOSNT WORK

```
CREATE VIEW view_2 AS
    SELECT 
        category_id, COUNT(*) AS product_sum
    FROM
        HM_category_products
    GROUP BY category_id

CREATE VIEW view_1 AS
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        HM_categories
            LEFT JOIN
        view_2 AS a ON HM_categories.id = a.category_id;


SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(product_sum)
        FROM
            view_1
        WHERE
            parent_id = final.id) as product_count
FROM
    HM_categories AS final;
```

that way you will get the product of a parent category, your only missing a CASE on the last select "product_count" to the child categorys, but that sum its easy because you already hav it on the view_1 (again sorry for my english)

Comment: It would help if u post your data shema and some rows of example data.

Comment: @hirasingh If you can't be polite to those attempting to help, don't ask for help.

Comment: @Melon I am getting an error "#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause "

Comment: @HiraSingh it was a litle mistake, but please read all my anwser: DISCLAIMER: THIS QUERY ITS JUST EXAMPLE, IT DOSNT WORK